# With SSML phoneme tags using IPA phonetic symbols, how can I insert pauses to slow down pronounciation?

Tags: phonetics, ipa, phonemes, software, phonetic-symbols

### Note

For my text to speech engine (I use Cereproc, William Voice).
The engine can be used on the website here:
https://www.cereproc.com/
and it supports the ssml tags used in this question..

### Backstory

I am building an acronymn interpreter that will clearly dilineate the acronymn as well as account for nuances like this:

```
IEDS -> I, E, Dees
```

instead of

```
IEDS -> I, E, Dee, Es
```

I only mention this, as this is why I can not use Cereproc's

```
<say-as interpret-as='characters'>IEDS</say-as>
```

---

Anyway, with phonemes, I am being tripped up here:

```
<phoneme alphabet="IPA" ph="ˈaɪ ˈiː dˈiːz ">IEDS</phoneme>
```

sounds something like "Iyee'Edees", giving a stupid sound artifact. I could do this:

```
 <phoneme alphabet="IPA" ph="ˈaɪ">I</phoneme>
 <phoneme alphabet="IPA" ph="ˈiː">E</phoneme>
 <phoneme alphabet="IPA" ph="dˈiːz">DS</phoneme>
```

But now the issue is the pause between each sound is too long.

### Question

Thus, in the IPA phonetic alphabet, what symbols could I place in between:

```
ˈaɪ
ˈiː
dˈiːz
```

To give the pause I need to adequately space out those sounds so each letter is pronounced in full?

Answer (score 2):

So in researching the question, I ended up finding an answer.

While it does not give me full control over the pausing, adding a period after each block of phonetic characters added the perfect amount of spacing, thus:

```
<phoneme alphabet="IPA" ph="  ˈaɪ. ˈiː. dˈiː.z ">IEDS</phoneme>
```

Works perfectly.